# How to get info if any Monitoring tool (DB performance Analyzer) stops working?

Tags: sql-server, performance, monitoring, performance-tuning

What is the Reason behind if SQL monitor for Production stopped working? what is the reason for this? I checked on Licensing, SQL server permissions, No Updates/Patching and Remote admin connections everything is alright. It might be cause of over load or OS issues effect SQL monitor? Any specific reason?

Comment: What do your wait stats look like? Any THREADPOOL waits? Once THREADPOOL happens, monitoring tools won't be able to collect data. You can see what happens leading up to it. And you can see what's happening during it if you use the Remote DAC for troubleshooting.

Comment: I/O waits 40% & others 60%, yes there is Threadpool waits 1034581333 (wait_time_ms), Remote DAC is enabled. How can I check what's the cause by using remote DAC?

Comment: Log into the server using Remote DAC and start troubleshooting blocking. THREADPOOL occurs when you run out of worker threads, usually due to huge blocking chains. Need to resolve why the blocking is occurring in order to resolve THREADPOOL and why the monitoring tool stops collecting data.

Comment: What version of sql server and edition u are using ? What is maxdop and cost threshold of parallelism set to ?

Comment: @Kin I am using SQL server 2008 (SP3) and Enterprise edition. MAXDOP is 8 and Cost threshold of Parallelism is 50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are encountering THREADPOOL waits, which occurs when the instance has run out of available worker threads. New logins will be denied, and lots of queries will be just waiting.

To troubelshoot THREADPOOL waits, connect with the Remote DAC and check current activity. You'll likely see huge blocking chains. You'll need to resolve or reduce the blocking to resolve the THREADPOOL waits.

Some Microsoft engineers will say to increase worker threads on the instance, but that doesn't help in my experience. It just means it'll take longer before THREADPOOL is encountered.

Things that might resolve THREADPOOL waits:

- Adjusting Max Degree of Parallelism and Cost Threshold for Parallelism so that less queries go parallel and thus fewer worker threads are needed
- Adding indexes
- Refactoring queries
- RCSI
- etc

For more information on THREADPOOL waits, check out these links (disclaimer: I work for Brent Ozar Unlimited):

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/05/connections-slow-sql-server-threadpool/
https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/threadpool/
http://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2011/10/25/troubleshooting-threadpool-waits/